# How do your write Xamarin platform specific code in a .net standard library?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-standard

How do your write Xamarin platform specific code in a .net standard library?

I want to use namespaces like `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS` in a .Net Standard Library..

Use case: I want to develop a .net library for my apps which includes a video player for the various platforms. This video player also has to interact with other code in the .net library.

Or is the answer I need to use a shared project or portable library?

Comment: You, by definition, cannot include platform specific code in a cross platform library.  A cross platform library can only include cross platform code.  I'd suggest you look at some common Xamarin plugins on github to see how they are architected - most will have a common shared library as well as platform specific libraries.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/video-player/

Comment: @magicandre1981 thanks I saw that and have read it.

Answer (score 3):

You should not include platform specific code or use namespaces like the one you mentioned in your .NET Standard Library, the reason is that .NET is just a runtime environment.

It’s not the the main runtime environment that you would use on iOS or Android. These platforms use Mono - not .NET. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/deepdive?pivots=windows) or [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/net-core-1-0-net-framework-xamarin-the-whatand-when-to-use-it/) to see more details for how its structured.

If you need to execute something from your .NET Standard project which is related to platform-specific behavior, use Dependency Injection or Custom Renderers.

Comment: So I was thinking I'd create a platform project for my platform unique code- then define Custom Renderers.. Then I can include those in my Xamarin.Forms code as part of the .Net Library right?

Comment: Yes and no. Depends on what do you want to implement. I would suggest you to use Custom Renderer if you are trying to create your own control or component which is based on some default control or component (e.g. you want to create CustomEntry which will have some extended functionality and design comparing to default Entry). But if you want to extend or to access some functionality in the platform specific, then you can go with Dependency Injection (e.g. you want to dynamically turn on bluetooth when the user clicks some button in your app with previously asking him for a permission...)